# Update all values in a column in DASK array

Tags: arrays, numpy, dask

I have a large dask array containing approx 300 million records and 3 numeric columns
It looks like roughly like (first few records):

```
2345 947  23
12   234  924
9    8    0
349  276  345
etc...
```

I would like to add say 100 on to all the values contained in column 2 such that I get the below dask array. Any ideas?

```
2345 1047  23        
12   334  924          
9    108    0    
349  376  345      
etc...
```

Comment: You say array, but you mention columns: is this a 2D array or a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might to just be switch it over to a `DataFrame` and do the assignment there before switching back to an array:

```py
df = darr.to_dask_dataframe(columns=["a", "b", "c"])
df["b"] += 100
darr = df.to_dask_array()
darr.compute()
```

This also has the benefit of being fairly obvious as to what is happening.

---

I also took a shot at this using a [generalized ufunc](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-gufunc.html) -- I couldn't get `da.apply_gufunc` to work for me in combination with `np.add.at` but I'm still working to grok ufuncs myself so there's likely a faster or more compact way to do it but this appears to work:

```py
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

darr = da.array([
    [2345, 947, 23], 
    [12,   234, 924],
    [9,    8,   0],
    [349,  276, 345]])

def add_at(arr, at, val):
    np.add.at(arr, at, val)
    return arr

gufunc_add_at = da.gufunc(add_at, 
                          signature="(i),(),()->(i)", 
                          output_dtypes=darr.dtype, 
                          vectorize=True)

gufunc_add_at(darr, 1, 100).compute()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit clunky but seems to work

```
import dask.array as da

darr = da.array([
    [2345, 947, 23], 
    [12,   234, 924],
    [9,    8,   0],
    [349,  276, 345]])
print(darr.compute())
x=darr[:,0].reshape(4,1).compute()
y=(darr[:,1] + 100).reshape(4,1).compute()
z=darr[:,2].reshape(4,1).compute()

t= da.stack([x,y,z], axis=1).reshape(4,3)
t.compute()
```

Output:

```
[[2345  947   23]
 [  12  234  924]
 [   9    8    0]
 [ 349  276  345]]
array([[2345, 1047,   23],
       [  12,  334,  924],
       [   9,  108,    0],
       [ 349,  376,  345]])
```

This is possibly an improvement to my first answer

```
from dask.array import from_array, add
from numpy import array

darr = da.array([
    [2345, 947, 23], 
    [12,   234, 924],
    [9,    8,   0],
    [349,  276, 345]])

vector = from_array(array([[0],[100],[0]]))
add(darr.T, vector).T.compute()
```

Output

```
array([[2345, 1047,   23],
       [  12,  334,  924],
       [   9,  108,    0],
       [ 349,  376,  345]])
```